# What is the state vector of a displaced (single-mode) squeezed vacuum state in the quadrature basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, coherent-states, squeezed-states

I've been hunting through the quantum optics literature for the displaced squeezed state written in the $q$-quadrature basis ($p$-quad would be fine too, since it's just a Fourier transform), but it does not seem to be anywhere. Everything I have found has either been in the number basis (and yes, I could change basis from $n$ to $q$ but this would lead me down into special function hell), the quasi-probability/characteristic-function representation (where it's not clear to me how to back the state vector out of that), or just in terms of operators.

This all looks too complicated for what it seems *should* be a simple gaussian function.

To be concrete I'm looking for the function $f(q)$ in:

\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{D}(\alpha)\hat{S}(\xi)|0\rangle=\int\,dq\,f(q)\,|q\rangle
\end{eqnarray}

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Would you be interested in the Wigner function of such a state? It is not a very complicated expression.

Comment: Hey thanks. Is there any easy way to get the state vector out of the Wigner function? I'm not aware of one.

Comment: Start with the vacuum state and apply the transformations in order, their action on the quadrature operators is quite simple.